# select count(*) desde java executeQuery

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

¿Como puedo almacenar el numero que me devuelva el select count(*) en una variable ?

```
 public int contar_num_personajes() throws SQLException{
         Connection dbConnection = null ;
         Statement stm = null;
         int n= 0;
         String consulta_contar_num_personajes = "SELECT count(*)" +
                                                  "FROM personajes;";    
         dbConnection = get_conection();
         stm = dbConnection.createStatement();
         n = stm.executeQuery(consulta_contar_num_personajes);
         return n;
    }
```

Comment: me da este error al poner lo que me has dicho **error: java.lang.NullPointerException** @mmartinez7

Comment: Podrias colocar el stacktrace completo o comentarnos en que linea se produce la excepcion?

Comment: pues no se como ponerlo tio

Comment: En donde estas corriendo tu aplicación? Si es en un IDE como eclipse o netbeans en la consola deberías ver la traza completa. Ademas puedes utilizar el debugger para llegar hasta el punto donde se produce la excepción y ver que variable era nula. Para agregarlo simplemente edita tu respuesta con esa información.

Comment: a ver, me quieres decir modificar el try catch apra q me de ma sinfo? si es asi, no tengo ni idea, no me salen metodos de stack trace. nunca lo use

Comment: Momentaneamente podrias quitar el try catch para que en consola se vea la traza completa. Ademas podrias colocar todo tu código (el bloque try-catch no figura en tu pregunta), e insisto, debuggear en estas situaciones es lo mejor.

Comment: **run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
 at Test.Test.main(Test.java:26)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
**

Comment: La excepción que obtienes no es la que reportas (NullPointerException) y no parece tener que ver con la pregunta original. Podría ser un problema del IDE y del código que tiene en caché, prueba hacer clean y build de tu proyecto. Si el problema persiste investiga y llegado el caso trasladalo a una nueva pregunta, colocando tu código completo para no desvirtuar el tema original de la pregunta que abriste

Answer (score 2):

Antes que nada `executeQuery` es un método para ejecutar una única consulta del tipo `select`, por ende no solo no es necesario indicar el final de la sentencia con `";"` sino que en varios drivers obtendrás la execpción `ORA-00911: invalid character`. La razón es que `";"` no es parte de la sintaxis sino un separador de sentencias utilizado por herramientas CLI. Puedes leer mas sobre esto [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728377/wheres-my-invalid-character-ora-00911)

Sobre tu pregunta:

> como puedo almacenar el numero que me devuelva el select count en una
>   variable ?

Puedes utilizar [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) para almacenar el resultado de tu consulta.

En tu consulta sabes que vas a obtener un único valor y es un entero, por lo que lo correcto sería acceder a través de [ResultSet.getInt(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt(int)) pasándole como parámetro el primer índice (`1`)

```
public int contar_num_personajes() throws SQLException{ 
     int n= 0;
     Connection  dbConnection = get_conection();
     Statement stm = dbConnection.createStatement();
     // almaceno resultado de consulta en ResultSet
     ResultSet rs  = stm.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM personajes");
     // chequeo que el result set no sea vacío, moviendo el cursor a la 
     // primer fila. (El cursor inicia antes de la primer fila)
     if(rs.next()) {
       //Si hay resultados obtengo el valor. 
        n= rs.getInt(1);
     }
     // libero recursos
     stm.close();
     dbConnection.close();
     return n;
}
```