# Java + BD metodo que me devuelva el num. personajes que hay

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo una BD y una aplicación de Java, de la BD nos olvidamos, centrémonos en la App, he creado una conexión a una base de datos que **SI** funciona, muy bien. Ahora me propongo a crear un método en JAVA que me devuelva un entero, el problema que me surge es

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException      at
>   Conexion.Conexion.contar_num_personajes(Conexion.java:58)      at
>   Test.Test.main(Test.java:34)

he mirado y no me deberia dar eso, es algo en lo que soy nuevo y me esfuerzo para aprender cada dia mas, me da la exception de `NullPointer`

```
package Conexion;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Conexion {

    private Connection co;

    public Conexion() {
        this.co = null;
    }

    public Connection get_conection() {
        return this.co;

    }

    public boolean conectar() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        /*
         Connection c = null;
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         //el metodo getConnection() hay que adaptarlo para conectarlo a mi base de daots de hostinguer
         c = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306//");
         Statement stm = c.createStatement();
         System.out.println("Conectado correctamente a la Base de Datos de 'League Of Leguends'");
         this.co = c;

         */
        boolean conectado = false;
        Connection c = null;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        c = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/LEAGUE_OF_LEGENDS", "miusuario", "micontraseña");
        Statement stm = c.createStatement();
        conectado = true;
        System.out.println("Conectado correctamente a la Base de datos : LEAGUE OF LEGUENDS");

        if (conectado == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }


    }

    public int contar_num_personajes() throws SQLException {
        int n = 0;
         Connection dbConnection = get_conection();
        Statement stm = dbConnection.createStatement();
        // almaceno resultado de consulta en ResultSet
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM personajes");
        // chequeo que el result set no sea vacío, moviendo el cursor a la 
        // primer fila. (El cursor inicia antes de la primer fila)
        if (rs.next()) {
            //Si hay resultados obtengo el valor. 
            n = rs.getInt(1);
        }
        // libero recursos
        stm.close();
        dbConnection.close();
        return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Tienes alguna pregunta?

Comment: Mi problema es que el metodo contar_num_perseonajes()** me da un error

Comment: **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Conexion.Conexion.contar_num_personajes(Conexion.java:58)
 at Test.Test.main(Test.java:34)**

Comment: porque me dice que es nulo? si esta aparentemente bien

Comment: Siendo esta la 18ª pregunta (sin contar las que hayas borrado), creo que ya deberías saber que pedimos que se explique qué problema tienes, qué esperas obtener y qué resultado obtienes. Por no hablar de cómo formatear el código. Realmente creo que tendrías que esforzarte un poco más.

Comment: No lo pongas en comentarios, edita tu pregunta y formula correctamente tu problema. Lee por favor [mcve]

Comment: @SJuan76 no se como se formatea codigo, si no tranquilo q lo haria

Comment: @Selito95 No entiendo tu pregunta. quieres que leamos todo tu código y que te demos una respuesta, deberías explicar que hace tu código y donde tienes problemas, te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta.

Comment: Ah sí, y que no nos gustan los duplicados: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/87349/select-count-desde-java-executequery

Comment: mejor asi ????????

Answer (score 1):

Te da el NullException ya que en el metodo get_conection() que es el que usas para obtener la conexion que imagino que previamente has conectado con el metodo conectar(), te devuelve una conexion nula, que es la que has declarado como "co", que en el constructor principal de la clase la defines como null. Se supone que en el metodo conectar() deberias setear la variable "co" por la varible "c" que estas usando internamente en el metodo, en lugar de usar la variable de la clase que has hecho. Creo que esta bastante claro.
Modifica el metodo conectar() algo como esto:

```
public boolean conectar() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        /*
         Connection c = null;
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         //el metodo getConnection() hay que adaptarlo para conectarlo a mi base de daots de hostinguer
         c = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306//");
         Statement stm = c.createStatement();
         System.out.println("Conectado correctamente a la Base de Datos de 'League Of Leguends'");
         this.co = c;

         */
        boolean conectado = false;
        Connection c = null;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        c = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/LEAGUE_OF_LEGENDS", "miusuario", "micontraseña");
        Statement stm = c.createStatement();
        conectado = true;
        System.out.println("Conectado correctamente a la Base de datos : LEAGUE OF LEGUENDS");
        this.co = c;
        if (conectado == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }


    }
```

Ya lo tenias bien, pero nose porque has comentado la linea y se te habra olvidado volverla a declarar.